# Where is directory temp of nuxeo?

Tags: nuxeo, nuxeo-js-client

I need to know what is the address of the folder temp of nuxeo,
and what is your size?

Comment: Do you mean the "temporary folder"?

Comment: What is the size of what? Is it a survey about how much free space are the Nuxeo administrators used to?

Comment: What is your Nuxeo version? And what is the relation with the nuxeo-js-client tag you set?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the value of `nuxeo.tmp.dir` parameter?

See the [Configuration Parameters Index (nuxeo.conf) on doc.nuxeo.com](https://doc.nuxeo.com/x/QQA7).

Please review your question including answers to the three comments I posted. Thanks.